# Filtering results using LIKE

Tags: attributes, collection, collection-filtering

Consider these three "haystack" strings:

a) `foo bar`

b) `welcome to foo bar industries`

c) `foo barer`

And now my "needle":

`foo bar`

(Heh)

I would like my filter to match my needle with haystack strings a & b but not c. I have tried:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%'.$needle.'%'));
```

But the above matches with c.

I also tried:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '% '.$needle.' %')); // Note the spaces
```

The above only matches with b.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Give this a try and see if it fits:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array(
    array('like' => '% '.$needle.' %'), //spaces on each side
    array('like' => '% '.$needle), //space before and ends with $needle
    array('like' => $needle.' %') // starts with needle and space after
));
```

Passing the second parameter as an array of arrays will concatenate the conditions using `OR`

Comment: That works :) Didn't know about the array trick, thanks.

Comment: With custom / non-eav models ```addAttributeToFilter``` should be replace with ```addFieldToFilter```.

Comment: Is there a way to determine which array returned a result? I am using this method to search a custom model collection (name,description,alternate_name fields) and I'd like to know if the result was hit because of the description (to include additional UI element on search results).

Comment: @pspahn Not a straight forward one. You can loop through the results after the select is executed and check if the needle is found in any of the fields you want.

Comment: Hey @Marius how to apply like filter on custom collection I've tried 
`->addFieldToFilter('store_name', array(
     array('like' => '% '.$search_name.' %'), //spaces on each side
                            array('like' => '% '.$search_name), //space before and ends with $search_name
                            array('like' => $ `
but returning nothing

Answer (score 9):

A possible solution is to use `REGEXP` instead of `LIKE`:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('regexp' => '[[:<:]]'.$needle.'[[:>:]]'));
```

From the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html):

> **[[:<:]], [[:>:]]**
>
> These markers stand for word boundaries. They match the beginning and
>   end of words, respectively. A word is a sequence of word characters
>   that is not preceded by or followed by word characters. A word
>   character is an alphanumeric character in the alnum class or an
>   underscore (_).

Note that if `$needle` can contain characters that have special meanings in POSIX regular expressions, you need to escape them. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024188/php-function-to-escape-mysql-regexp-syntax

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer doesn't work properly.
It's checking only space before and after the text.

Suppose, you have following list

- Jacket
- Summer Jacket
- Winter Jacket

Now if you try to search with **jacket** using the accepted answer, it will return only **Summer Jacket** and **Winter Jacket**

I think following solution is better

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%' . $needle. '%'));
```

Comment: It would not cover case (c) from the question (i.e. also match "jacketing"). Instead, a fourth condition `['eq' => $needle]` could be added to find exact matches (or better, use the regex solution which finds all boundaries, not only spaces)

Comment: above code is able to find the exact matches. I checked it

Comment: I did not doubt that. But it finds more, which it should not. At least if you have the same requirements as in the original question: Do not find "foo barer" when searching "foo bar"

Comment: Yes, you are right. The accepted answer was not working for me properly so I suggested the simple one-line filter for getting the likewise items.