# Magento product search by name is not working

Tags: magento-1.8

```
$needle= $_GET["singleid"];

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();

$_productCollection = $collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array(
    array('like' => '% '.$needle.' %'), //spaces on each side
    array('like' => '% '.$needle), //space before and ends with $needle
    array('like' => $needle.' %') // starts with needle and space after
));
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){
   echo $_product->getId().'</br>';
   echo $_product->getName().'</br>';
   echo $_product->getProductUrl().'</br>';
   echo $_product->getPrice().'</br>';
}
```

This is my code.

```
$needle= $_GET["singleid"];

$collections = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();


$collection = $collections->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%'.$needle.'%'));
echo $collection->getSelect();
```

my sql query

```
SELECT `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, IF(at_name.value_id > 0, at_name.value, at_name_default.value) AS `name` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_name_default` ON (`at_name_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_name_default`.`attribute_id` = '71') AND `at_name_default`.`store_id` = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_name` ON (`at_name`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_name`.`attribute_id` = '71') AND (`at_name`.`store_id` = 1) WHERE (IF(at_name.value_id > 0, at_name.value, at_name_default.value) LIKE '%s%')
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `->load()` before using `->addAttributeToFilter()`.

When calling load the collection is fetched from the database, and thus not filterable using sql queries anymore.

You should remove the `->load()` part and it should work:

```
$needle= $_GET["singleid"];

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');


$collection = $collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%'.$needle.'%'));
echo $collection->getSelect();
$collection->load();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove space after `%`

```
$_productCollection = $collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array(
    array('like' => '%'.$needle.'%'), //spaces on each side
    array('like' => '%'.$needle), //space before and ends with $needle
    array('like' => $needle.'%') // starts with needle and space after
));
```

your query is going to search word with `space`

**EDIT**

```
$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%'.$needle.'%'));
```

hope my correction will work for you.

Comment: my Output:1</br>test product</br>http://localhost/magento/test-product.html</br>5.0000</br when i give $needle="z" but do not have  prodcucts with Z

Comment: you want to search word with space ?

Comment: i referred this link [please check](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11082/filtering-results-using-like)

Comment: use my updated answer you just need to use one only for search by name, pls don't forget to acpt ans if it works for u

Comment: again same result

Comment: did u refresh your cache and also `echo $collection->getSelect(); // to print query` run it to your DB first and see

Comment: remove all like just use my edit content

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23316/discussion-between-siby-thomas-and-liyakat).

Comment: same result again

Comment: paste your sql query

Comment: `$needle= $_GET["singleid"];

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();

$_productCollection = $collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%'.$needle.'%'));`

Comment: i mean sql query `echo  $_productCollection->getSelect();` it will print sql query in web browser and run it to your mysql window. or add here how your sql query looks?

Comment: query is very long so i can not post here

Comment: you may edit your question to add sql query.

Comment: @SibyThomas,its been really hard to guide you.My answer is almost same  with your sql query.you should have to give at least some credit.

Answer (score 0):

answered here.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965309/magento-product-collection-by-name/29982982#29982982

```
$searchstring = 'Slim fit';
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getCollection() 
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%'.$searchstring.'%'));

foreach ($productCollection as $_product){

            echo $_product->getId().'</br>';
            echo $_product->getName().'</br>';
            echo $_product->getProductUrl().'</br>';
            echo $_product->getPrice().'</br>';

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `load()` function in collection, as the collection-data is autoloaded for both Flat and EAV table collections.

Also prefer `addFieldToFilter` over `addAttributeToFilter` as it allows fields of other product-related tables also to be joined with collection-query. Like below:

```
$needle= $_GET["singleid"];

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$_productCollection = $collection->addFieldToFilter('name', array(
    array('like' => '% '.$needle.' %'), //spaces on each side
    array('like' => '% '.$needle), //space before and ends with $needle
    array('like' => $needle.' %') // starts with needle and space after
));

foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) {
   echo $_product->getId().'</br>';
   echo $_product->getName().'</br>';
   echo $_product->getProductUrl().'</br>';
   echo $_product->getPrice().'</br>';
}
```

Hope this works for you!!!