# M1 get collection fail

Tags: magento-1.9, product-collection

I have a problem getting the collection, I have two shops and each one have their sku prepended the shop code like EN_1234 FR_3513. I tried to get the collection like always:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('like' => $shop.'%'));
```

But from a time to now it only works for one shop, EN. I saw the query and it's getting their data from `catalog_product_flat_1` where all the products are from EN, but the products of FR are in `catalog_product_flat_4`.

I tried to reindex by console and with the admin, but nothing.
What can I do?

UPDATE

```
$shop = 'EN' or $shop = 'FR'
```

I see part of the problem is because I'm calling a script I have in the root of magento, If I use this same function inside the model all works.

Comment: can you please add `$shop` variable value

Comment: Use Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(0) to force collection to get all products, give it a try, additionally what is the value of $shop?

Comment: @Adnan `Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(0)`, works in part, because I would want to get the collection by website, but it's a good point, thanks

Comment: @Adnan I'll accept your answer as correct, if you can write as it, I'll approbe it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your feedback @oootramas, Put

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(0)
```

before the collection and it will fetch all the products of all stores, like

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(0);
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('like' => $shop.'%'));
```

It will force Magento to get all products from all stores, by default it fetches the product from current store.

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')    
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('like' => $shop.' %')) // starts with needle and space after
```

[reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/11084/20064)

Comment: the sku is like EN_134, if I put a space they look for EN _134, and it doesn't exist