# Magento 2 Get product collection filter by atributes does not give the exact match

Tags: product-attribute, collection, magento2.2.2, product-collection

I have created a filter to get product bellow is an examples:

```
$filter = array(
  array('attribute' => 'color', 'eq' => '2'),//id of option
  array('attribute' => 'size', 'eq' => '5'),// tried with many variations 'like', '=', 'in'
  array('attribute' => 'length', 'eq' => '8')
)

$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter($filter)
            ->load()->getItems();
```

The above in the front end the selection is:

[image]

But my first result is ->
[image]

I am only able to see exact matching filter somewhere down to the 10th result. not ideal.

How can I get just the exact match result? in this example I should **only** get product that has

```
color:blue, size:2 length:30
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, There is another way which gives exact result explained here:

[Filtering results using LIKE](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11082/filtering-results-using-like)

code taken from above link:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array(
 array('like' => '% '.$needle.' %'), //spaces on each side
 array('like' => '% '.$needle), //space before and ends with $needle
 array('like' => $needle.' %') // starts with needle and space after
));
```

But my case is a foreach loop so the final result using the example above is:

```
...
   $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
     foreach ($filter as $key=>$value){
       $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter($key, 
           array('like' => '%'.$value.'%'));
        };
   $productCollection->load()->getItems();
...
```

**NOTE: no need extra space for me needed as mentioned!**

This work as a treat!